# Refering to a textfield in Gridpane

Tags: javafx, textfield, gridpane

alright. So to give ya'll some background info: I'm programming a sudoku, haven't worked too much with GUI but done much research.

I've created a 2 for loops creating a 9x9 Gridpane filled with textfields with the following code

```
GridPane grid = new GridPane();

for(int x =0; x < 9; x++){
    for(int y= 0; y < 9; y++){
        TextField textField = new TextField("0");
        textField.setStyle("-fx-pref-width: 2em;");
        GridPane.setConstraints(textField, y, x);
        grid.getChildren().add(textField);
    }
}
```

Now what I do is to have a clear way of taking - for example the coordinate 
[2][5] to return to an 2d array and compare to the answer sheet. My problem is to specify a coordinate in my gridpane.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the text fields in an array:

```
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
TextField[][] textFields = new TextField[9][9] ;

for(int x =0; x < 9; x++){
    for(int y= 0; y < 9; y++){
        TextField textField = new TextField("0");
        textField.setStyle("-fx-pref-width: 2em;");
        GridPane.setConstraints(textField, y, x);
        grid.getChildren().add(textField);
        textFields[x][y]=textField ;
    }
}
```

Then you can access any element `(x,y)` with `textFields[x][y].getText()`.